# Is it possible to create a new Firestore database every time a new user is created in Firebase?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-firestore

I've been using Firebase in android apps for a while now and I was wondering if it would be at all possible for when a user creates an account (using Firebase authentication) it also creates a Firestore database linked to that account and only that account? I would also like it so that when the user deletes their account, the database is removed with it. I was looking into other database options but Firestore seems to be the best option for what I want to do.

Let me know if this needs clarification!

Comment: You could create a separate *document* for each user, and store the data in that document specifically. If that's not what you want, please explain the benefit that you want to get from isolating each user to his own database.

Comment: I'm attempting to design an inventory management system and I want it so that when a customer signs up through the app, a new database is assigned to them. I was wanting to use Firestore that I can later create iOS and web apps.

Comment: Yes, and you can do that very thing without creating a new database - you just need to make sure that documents you search in database could be displayed to the user. Basically, make sure to set the user as the owner of a document, and don't show the document to anyone else unless user allows you to. See more [in this article](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/role-based-access).

Comment: And also see this article: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case one firestore database will work perfectly. You will need to do some thinking on database structure

This video will help https://youtu.be/haMOUb3KVSo

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't create a database for each user, it will become really messy when your code and userbase grows. Also [there is no way to create databases programmatically](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/106).

Comment: Ah, I was afraid that might be the case! I know I'm going off on a tangent here, but would you happen to know what kind of process apps like [Sortly](https://www.sortly.com/) use for creating user databases? I'm wanting to create a widely available, cross-platform inventory management system but built on Firestore backend.

Comment: I don't know about that exact app, but every similar project that I've worked on uses a single database. You just have to relate every object to its owner, so the user only sees his data.